The file in the editor is not runnable - IntelliJ
i reinstalled the whole windows system because of a trojan that i had.
I installed java JDK 21, as i need it to code minecraft plugins.
I installed the plugin MinecraftDevelopment as usual, done everything the same way i'd do it before reinstalling windows, but when i create a new project the run button is grayed out, and if i hover on it it says "the file in the editor is not runnable".
Even by opening a project that i used to work on before resetting, the error i get is the same. What am i missing?
I tried setting the folder src as root, invalidating cache, repairing IDE, making new project, reinstalling intellij, importing spigot manually,. but nothing seems to be working.


Have you checked, your Java Runtime is set correctly in IntelliJ?
"file is not runnable" usually was a problem with the runtime or the project type for me.
Bear in mind, that java can work from the terminal/powershell but can still be unconfigured in the IDEs settings.

What file are you trying to run?

@Sweeper i simply created the project, it creates the src folder, the main java class, and the resources folder with plugin.yml, it looks to me like it loaded the spigot etc, but even if i dont add any single line of code, the run button is grayed out.

So you are trying to run a minecraft plugin from IntelliJ? That is not possible as far as I know. You should build the project, move the output jar to the plugins folder, and start/reload the server. Were you able to directly run it before? That doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

@Sweeeper sorry for any misunderstanding, i used to write the code on intellij, compiling the plugin and getting the .jar, then putting the compiled jar into plugins folder of the minecraft server

Yeah that sounds about right. So just do mvn clean package to build the jar then. Add that as a run configuration if you want.

@Sweeper damn that worked thanks, is there any way to "bind" the command to the compile button so i dont have to open the console and run the command each time?

Add it as a run configuration. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-maven.html

It looks like you have not added a run configuration.
For a Spigot plugin, you can use mvn clean package to build a jar and install it by moving the jar to the plugins folder of your server.
You can add mvn clean package as a Maven run configuration so that clicking on the run button builds the jar.
Click on the "Current File" dropdown and select "Edit Configurations"

Then add a new configuration using the Maven template. Write clean package in the box under "Run".

Then you can select the newly added run configuration using the dropdown and the run button will be enabled.

Appreciate the help, everything works fine now
